# Overwriting one branch with an other branch in git

Tags: git, github

I have a branch "`Development`". I added a new branch "`details`" and pushed code in it multiple times. However I realised that the code pushed was incorrect.

I want to do reset changes by pushing `development` to `details`. How can I force push `development` code into `details` branch

Comment: Is all of this happening on your local machine, or have you actually pushed code to another (remote) machine/server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
git checkout details
git reset --hard origin/development     # Set details to origin/development. All your changes of details will be lost
git push origin details --force
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset everything then why not delete the `details` branch and make a new branch based on `development` branch